# Scroll Issues on new iOS 13 (for both Safari and Chrome)

Tags: html, css

I have a private app which shows a popup and flipping that modal back and forth to display some products.
Everything works fine on PC, Androids phone and tablet, iPhone with `iOS < v13.`
But yesterday when I upgraded my phone to the latest `iOS (13)`, now I can't scroll my popup content anymore.

Everything work fine except for

```
iOS 13.0 (both with Chrome v77.0.x and Safari v13.0)
```

Here my code-pen to show that error 
https://codepen.io/hoangndt/pen/KKPEzpK

Thanks,

Comment: Obviously there is still no solution with IOS13.3.

Answer (score 0):

Some app developers are having scrolling issues with iOS 13. I know I am. Hopefully, there have been or will be soon in the next minor version.